# Appending html select box to page that is populated with MYSQL query results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database, append

Normally when creating dynamically populated drop-downs I'd use a simple foreach loop as below to get the data:

```
<select name="region" id="region" tabindex="1">
   <option value="">Select a Course</option>
   <?php foreach ( $courses as $course ) : ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $course->coursename; ?>"><?php echo $course->coursename; ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

*where $courses = select("SELECT * FROM courses");
```

etc etc

What I'm not sure is possible is to use this in anything like its current form inside a javascript function such as the one below that I've been using on some forms to append additional input fields per the requirements of the user. This works fine for a text input, for example (and as below I can use it if I type out each input option manually) but I'm not at all sure as to the best way to recreate the PHP/mySQL example above where javascript doesn't get in the way. I've tried to look into whether this could easily be done with AJAX but have not been able to find any examples of what I'm trying to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
                '<h4>Link #' + count + '</h4>&nbsp' 
                +'<select id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]">' + '<option>Select a Course</option>'+'</select>');

    });
});
</script>
```

Many thanks for any advice about the best way to do this.

Comment: What's your goal? What are you trying to do? You haven't clearly stated the problem or issue you're having.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity. I've been using the javascript function above to append new text input fields which I then insert as another mySQL query. What I want to achieve is being able to append a select box populated dynamically with mySQL query data (the example at the top is how I've done it previously).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update - I eventually managed to answer my own question - solution as per the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
$(function(){
    $('p#add_field').click(function(){
        count += 1;
        $('#container2').append(
                '<strong>Golf Course ' + count + '</strong>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp' 
                +'<select id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]">' + "<?php foreach ( $courses as $course ) { $name = $course->coursename; ?>"+"<?php echo '<option value=\''.htmlspecialchars($name).'\'>'.$name.'</option>'; ?>"+"<?php } ?>"+'</select><br />')

    });
});
</script>
```